# Check if records are more than one for a record in joined table

Tags: mysql, database, yii, yii1.x

I have two tables: `business` and `sms_content_business` And this is the schema for both tables:
For `business` Table:
[image]

For `sms_content_business` Table:
[image]

Now what I want to achieve is to get all the businesses for which `is_topbrand = 1` there is at least one record in the `sms_content_business` table and I am doing it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `business` WHERE is_topbrand=1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sms_content_business` scb JOIN `business` b ON b.id=scb.business_id) > 0
```

But it doesn't do what I intend to do. Also how to do it using Yii 1 `CDBcriteria` class? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql query, you can use `exists`;

```
select b.*
from business b
where b.is_topbrand = 1
and exists(
    select 1
    from sms_content_business scb
    where b.id = scb.business_id
)
```